# Return integer when user read the sms

Tags: android

I want to do some activity on sms after user read it, 
so how can my background service in android know that particular sms is now read(when my service start work) to react for some task.

Is there system generate any integer when user read sms? If it generate than how will I get it?

Answer (score 0):

The SmsMessage `getStatusOnICC()` method will return you the status of the message. Whether it is received, read or unread. Check the following links for more details:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getStatusOnIcc%28%29

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#STATUS_ON_ICC_READ

Comment: Hi, karan i go through it,my task is not to know the status only but to know when the status is change from unread to read 

Ex. BroadcastReceiver override OnReceive method to get receiving sms.

Comment: Hi, I don't know any whether any intent/method is called when the message status changes.